# decimal to toFixed() in recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

```
<YAxis
          orientation="right"
          // YAxis={{
          //   tickFormatter: (Estimated_minutes) =>
          //     parseFloat(Estimated_minutes).toFixed(0),
          // }}
          formatter={formatYAxis}
          type="number"
          yAxisId="2"
          dataKey="Estimated_minutes"
          fill="#000000"
        />
```

How to format the integer value in `Yaxis`? I have tried `toFixed` but it's still giving me the error. Is there any other way I can implement this?

Comment: Please add the error message to the question

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal reproducible example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
        <YAxis
          orientation="right"
          YAxis={{
            tickFormatter: (Estimated_minutes) =>
              parseFloat(Number(Estimated_minutes).toFixed(0)),
          }}
          formatter={formatYAxis}
          type="number"
          yAxisId="2"
          dataKey="Estimated_minutes"
          fill="#000000"
        />
```

Comment: not giving me an error but that code its not working what you have implement @mateonunez

Comment: Can you add a snippet? @AyushKumar

Comment: ``` <YAxis
          orientation="right"
          YAxis={{
            tickFormatter: (Estimated_minutes) =>
              parseFloat(Number(Estimated_minutes).toFixed(0)),
          }}
          // formatter={formatYAxis}
          type="number"
          yAxisId="2"
          dataKey="Estimated_minutes"
          fill="#000000"
        />```@mateonunez

Answer (score 6):

This might help

```
<YAxis
   type="number"
   tickFormatter={(value) => value.toFixed(2)}
   domain={["dataMin", "auto"]}
   allowDecimals={true}
/>
```